# How can I understand the concept of Uncorporeality

Tags: rambam, theology, soul

Speaking of Corporality, one can describe it as a shape and as a consistence or a density.
Rambam 3rd article of principles states: "The belief in G‑d's non-corporeality, nor that He will be affected by any physical occurrences, such as movement, or rest, or dwelling" (In Chabad.org).
Question:
But how is Uncorporality defined ? Is it on the other end of a fuzzy spectrum which joins corporality at one end and uncorporality at the other end ? Or is it an "all or nothing" concept ?
My secondary question applies similarly to the Neshama as a part of God embedded in each person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashem has as much relevance to space, location and shape as does the concept of "1 + 1 = 2". Can you say where is "1 + 1 = 2"? On the one hand, you can't go to where this math truth resides, how much volume it occupies. It's meaningless to ask how many corners it has, or the shape of its curves. On the other, there is nowhere you can be in the universe where it's not true. The question of "where is 1 + 1 = 2" is both "nowhere' and "everywhere" because the question isn't meaningful.

Similarly, Hashem isn't eternal in the sense of having infinite time, but in the sense that time is not an applicable concept.

And the same when we discuss incorporeality. It's not that Hashem is 0% corporeal. It's that He would be entirely off the spectrum you would be trying to set up.

Your question is like asking about the literal, non-poetic, weight or color of a song.

Comment: With each attempt you make I feel cornered in another outlandish area. I do appreciate the examples you give though, much food for thought. Now, when you say "it's not that Hashem is 0% corporeal" does'nt this contradict the Rambam's statement (the belief in G-d's non-corporeality) ? Pioni5777

Comment: @Pioni5777, it is exactly in line with the Rambam's conception of Divine Attributes - that we can only describe what He isn't. He isn't embodied or disembodied; G-d is so far from the topic of embodiment your question has no meaning,

Comment: A helium balloon can be perfectly banaced so that is has no weight. Weight equals 0 pounds. How much does yellow weight? G-d has no body the way yellow has no weight. Not the way a helium balloon weighs 0.

Comment: Does it mean we are totaly alien to G-d and vice versa ?    Have you got a comment on the Neshama please ?

Comment: @Pioni5777, if you are asking from within the Rambam’s worldview, yes. Gd is totally Unlike anything we can comprehend.

Comment: I am pleased with the answer I got. Just wonder why this Q/A has been blurred from the beginning, and what action does it calls for ??